# Determining the big-O runtimes of these different loops

Tags: time-complexity

I have a series of questions in which I need feedback and answers. I will comment as to what I think, this is not a homework assignment but rather preparation for my exam.

**Q1:**

```
int val = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = i * 2)
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
       val++;
```

My answer is : `O(nlog(n))`

**Q2**

```
int val = 0;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = pow(i, k)) // k > 1 
  val++;
```

My answer is : `O(log(log(n))`

**Q3**

```
T(n) = 8T(n/2) + 2000*n^2 + n^e
```

Comment: Q3: have a look at the **Case 1 example**  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#:~:text=In%20the%20analysis%20of%20algorithms,Dorothea%20Haken%2C%20and%20James%20B.

Comment: Q1: `O(n)`, `t = k * n` where `k` depends on `n` but `k = 1..2` range

Comment: Q3: `O(n**3)` if `n^e` means `n in e-th` power where `e = 2.718282828...`

Comment: tnx! and Q2 is correct?

Comment: Q2 is OK: `O(log(log(n)))`